# Adding regular Activitys to ActionBarSherlock tabs

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

Im using this tutorial as my base code:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/

I had a project I built that targeted 2.1 , Then I had the brillant thought " Geee it sure would be swell to have one of those handy ActionBars ive been seeing around" Soon learned id have to switch my target build to 4.1 and figure out how to use ABS so that it could still be used on older versions of Android. Once I finally figured how to get the damn Actionbar from ABS to work I discovered my old Tabhost was now depreciated so id have to look into updating that also. Now ive found this tut which is simple enough to understand, but im wondering if there is a way to use Activitys for my tabs instead of fragments?  Or am I just best doing more research and figuring out how to convert my existing activitys to fragments?

```
public class BuhzHyve extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("onCreate Method Called","WIN WIN WIN");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i("onTabSelected Method Called","WIN WIN WIN");
        TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the support library in your project and bam, you can now use fragments.  Just make sure you are importing the Fragment from the support lib.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html